# How to parse multiple XML files in Node JS?

Tags: xml, node.js

I've got a bunch of XML files (~7000). I want to extract information from all these files, and output that information into a JSON file. I'm only interested in a couple of specific tags from the XML data.

Using [this xml parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-stream), I have been able to do this for one XML file, but when trying to do it for all of them I get "Error: EMFILE: too many open files" (even when using the [graceful-fs](https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs) module).

Does anyone have a solution to accomplish this task that they could suggest or point me towards? It does not seem to have already been asked here.

Thanks.

Comment: One of the way is to read file synchronously, parse it to json, close the stream. In this way, there will only one file open at a time. You can use asynchronous function to read the file synchronously to make it fast.